# Pandas SparseDataFrame from list of dicts

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to convert a list of Python dicts into a Pandas `DataFrame`.
Since every dict has different keys, it takes up too much memory. Since most of the values are NaN, a `SparseDataFrame` should be helpful in this case.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame(keyword_data).to_sparse(fill_value=.0)
```

This works, but takes up loads of memory because a DataFrame is created in the meanwhile, and sometimes raises `MemoryError`.

Is it possible to create a SparseDataFrame with this data without that step? The Pandas documentation doesn't help much in this case...
Doing this:

```
pandas.SparseDataFrame(keyword_data, default_fill_value=.0)
```

Raises:

> TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

---

The data looks something like:

```
[{'a': 0.672366,
  'b': 0.667276,
  # ...
 },
 {'c': 0.507752,
  'd': 0.532593,
  'e': 0.507793
  # ...
 },
 # ...
]
```

The keys are always strings, with different keys per dict, the values are floats.

Is there a way to create a `SparseDataFrame` directly from this data, without going through a regular `DataFrame`?

Comment: what are you going to do with this?

Comment: I was trying to represent keywords data in a dataframe with lots of columns (about 10x more than rows). I can probably find a better way to represent the same data, I was just wondering why the `SparseDataFrame` constructor doesn't work where `df.to_sparse()` does...

Comment: Sparse support is not that big now, so lots of open issues. You can use SparseDataFrame but you have to give it a dict of key->Series, and a conglomerated index already (You may have to directly construct the SparseSeries to avoid going dense->sparse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of pandas v1.0.0, `SparseDataFrame` and `SparseSeries` [were removed](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html#migrating).

There is no need for them anymore. Quoting [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html#migrating):

> There’s no performance or memory penalty to using a Series or DataFrame with sparse values, rather than a SparseSeries or SparseDataFrame.